# DNS record to link to website

Tags: domain-name-system, iis-8

I have the following website that I am trying to setup the DNS entry for:
[image]

If I add the following CNAME entry in DNS:

[image]

I am able to browse to the default website of the server:

[image]

But what I really want is to create a CNAME record that maps **manex.ampdomain.com** to **SERVER005.ampdomain.com/ManexCloud**.  How do I achieve this?  I have already tried to change the FQDN to **SERVER005.ampdomain.com/ManexCloud** but that does not work.

Comment: DNS does not work that way. DNS ties a domain name to an IP. The rest is up to your server.

Comment: What @ceejayoz said. Instead, you should probably just do the CNAME to the root and then use a redirect to direct the visitor to the inside directory (/ManexCloud)

Comment: **@David W**, how would I accomplish that?

Comment: You can either add another [Web site](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772514.aspx) or another [binding](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772514.aspx). Both done in IIS, not DNS: